# Mongo DB showing an error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Operation now in progress'

Tags: php, mongodb

Mongo DB showing an error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Operation now in progress' in PHP. How to resolve this error and why this error comes.

Answer (score 0):

This typically means the driver has issues connecting to the database. I've learned this through the very first result in Google when pasting your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Remon said, *"I have an error please help"* doesn't work very well when asking programming questions.

Usual things to make sure are, that Mongodb is running and you are connecting to the right `host:port` e.g.

`$m = new Mongo();`

If it's not in the localhost (your machine) and default port try this.

```
$con = new Mongo("mongodb://{$username}:{$password}@{$host}");
```

Also try to connect to the database using the `mongo` shell interface.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to connect to ObjectRocket. The solution was to add my IP to the ACLs and then I no longer got this error.